# CloudZoom overflow hidden

Tags: html, css

i am using CloudZoom, to zoom on image.

I have an image its in the div

```
.product_large_image  {width:370px;height:370px;background:#fff;border-radius:185px;text-align:center;overflow:hidden;box-shadow:0px 0px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);}
```

I has `overflow:hidden`, it's because this makes nice looking round effect.

But here is the problem, when i hover image and it zooms , CloudZoom shows the large image next to the main image, but US the larger image zoom is in the div witch says `overflow: hidden`, it hides that zoom effect image too.

Is there any chance to make that zoom image visible ? maybe with !important.

I think that we target that image and write something we could do it ?

```
<div class="product_large_image">
    <a href="img/index/products/01.jpg" rel="adjustX: 30, adjustY: -4" class="cloud-zoom " id="zoom1" style="display: block !important;">
        <img src="img/index/products/01_small.jpg" alt="" title="Procut zoom" >
    </a>
</div>
<ul class="pr_gallery">
    <li>
        <a href="img/index/products/01.jpg" class="cloud-zoom-gallery" rel="useZoom: 'zoom1', smallImage: 'img/index/products/01_small.jpg'">
            <img src="img/index/products/01.jpg" alt="01">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="img/index/products/02.jpg" class="cloud-zoom-gallery" rel="useZoom: 'zoom1', smallImage: 'img/index/products/02_small.jpg'"><img src="img/index/products/02.jpg" alt="02">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="img/index/products/03.jpg" alt="03"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the css rule to the image or to the  element
remove the overflow hiden of the wrapper

```
.product_large_image .cloud-zoom  {width:370px;height:370px;background:#fff;border-radius:185px;text-align:center;overflow:hidden;box-shadow:0px 0px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);}
```